# What data type is "Date" in Postgres?

Tags: entities, datetime, database

I don't have access to a client database, but need to know how a "Date" CCK field stores its information.
I'm using MySQL, and this easily found in the structure of the table. Anyone use Postgres and can check?

Is it a `timestamp` or a `date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need access to the database for this information?

Have you looked here?
http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/blob/b7502f3a86628e5c4995c01f20ac64d5cee5888b:/date.install

```
/**
 * @file
 * Install, update and uninstall functions for the Date module.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 */
function date_field_schema($field) {
  $db_columns = array();
  switch ($field['type']) {
    case 'datestamp':
      $db_columns['value'] = array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'sortable' => TRUE,
        'views' => TRUE,
      );
      break;
    case 'datetime':
      $db_columns['value'] = array(
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
        'pgsql_type' => 'timestamp without time zone',
        'sqlite_type' => 'varchar',
        'sqlsrv_type' => 'smalldatetime',
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'sortable' => TRUE,
        'views' => TRUE,
      );
      break;
    default:
      $db_columns['value'] = array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 20,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'sortable' => TRUE,
        'views' => TRUE,
      );
      break;
  }
  // ... more stuff
```

The answer to your question is that depending on the Drupal "Date" value you're storing it -- for `Postgres` it is 1 of the following values:

- (drupal field of) `datestamp` = `int` DBMS field
- (drupal field of)`datetime` = `timestamp without time zone` DBMS field
- (other drupal field of) date = `varchar` DBMS field analyzed by Date module on save and usage

**EDIT**

My answer is for Drupal 7. The same module API can be referenced for Drupal version 6 if needed. You didnt specify what version of Drupal you are using and "CCK" can be apart of both.

Comment: The CCK field in question appears as "Date" on the content type page. (As opposed to "Date (ISO)" or other options) 
In MySQL, it's stored as a datetime, so at looking this, it must indeed be the Postgres data type 'timestamp without time zone'